# Problems with defeating the three shamans in Necessary Sacrifice mission (Sith Inquisitor)

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I tried the fight against the three shamans in the mission "Necessary Sacrifice" multiple times. I only managed to kill the weak one. Is there some good strategy (Sorcerer Lvl 47) or do I have to get to a higher level/ask for help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use your starter companion (a tank). Set up your shield on your tank companion and stun one of the sages for 60 seconds. Run back so your companion and aggro the remaining two shamans — work on the weak one till it is dead then go for the harder one. Once both are dead, heal up and work on the third.